# Objective-C read/write to plist file //after trying 9999 different solutions

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist, read-write

Like I said in the subject, I'm facing some problems with both read and write to a .plist file. I already read a lot of possible implementations from other threads here and from a book, but still I can't make this to work, so I'd like to ask for your opinion. Right now this goes like this:

I have an array of movies arrayMovies in my shared instance data manager. I work my whole app based on this array. It's always "reachable" from every part of the app with just this:

```
[[iCultureDataManager sharedInstance]arrayMovies];
```

So when the app finishes loading, I initialize the arrayMovies from an array that is supposed to be in the .plist file, like this:

```
-(NSString* ) getFilePathForMovies{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"movies.plist"];
    return filePath;
}

- (NSArray *) getMovies{
    NSString *myPath = [self getFilePathForMovies];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];
    NSArray* movies;
    if(fileExists){
    movies = [[NSArray alloc ]initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
    }
    return movies;
    }
```

and in the init I just

```
_arrayMovies = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self getMovies]];
```

One thing I don't understand is why does the BOOL fileExists always returns false, like it's not finding the .plist file.

To save the array for the .plist file I do:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self addToMovies];
    NSLog(@"DidEnterBackground: Adding to Movies...");
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self addToMovies];
    NSLog(@"applicationWillEnterForeground: Adding to Movies...");
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive.  If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    */
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate: Adding to Movies...");
    [self addToMovies];
}

- (void) addToMovies{
    NSString *myPath = [self getFilePathForMovies];
    [[[iCultureDataManager sharedInstance]arrayMovies] writeToFile:myPath atomically:YES];
}

-(NSString* ) getFilePathForMovies{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"movies.plist"];
    return filePath;
}
```

I think it's pretty much this for the matters but if I can help you with some more information feel free to say, cause I really don't understand what is going on. I don't know if I'm writing to file wrong or reading it wrong or whatever else I'm doing wrong.

Thank you very much for your time and help,

PS: now I'm at the point where the fileExists always returns -1... :S

Comment: You should use stringByAppendingPathComponent instead of stringByAppendingString, because it will properly add the slash between components (you may already have the slash, but using the correct method will ensure that you do). Also, writeToFile:atomically: returns a BOOL indicating success or not, you should check that to see if you're write is actually happening.

Answer (score 1):

You imply that you are initializing your array with a list of movies that are in the plist file.  That would imply that you are starting with a plist file.  To access the read-only plist file that exists in your bundle, you use a different path like this:

```
-(NSString *)getOriginalFilePathForMovies {
    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"originalMovies" ofType:@"plist"];
    contentArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
}
```

Then to access the writable plist you need a path like you are using:

```
-(NSString* ) getFilePathForMovies{
    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"movies.plist"];
    return filePath;
}
```

So I would recommend doing this to initialize your array:

```
- (NSArray *)getMovies {
    NSString *myPath = [self getFilePathForMovies];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:myPath];
    NSArray* movies;
    if(fileExists){
        movies = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
    } else {
        movies = [[NSArray alloc]initiWithContentsOfFile:[self getOriginalFilePathForMovies]];
    return movies;
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two methods? I don't understand...What is the "originalMovies" for?

Comment: getOriginalFilePathForMovies reads the read-only file from your original bundle that ships with the app.  getFilePathForMovies gives you a path to a plist file to which you can both read and write.  This path is in your documents directory.

Comment: Do you have a plist file included with your app?

Comment: Yes, in my resources folder I've a movies.plist. Is that enough?

Comment: Did you change the @"originalMovies" in my getOriginalFilePathForMovies to "movies" then?  And does it open that file?

Comment: Yes I did and the file is empty. Only says Root. Do I need to add something to it?

Comment: Ahhh.. I misunderstood you.  I thought you had stuff movies you wanted to begin with.  If you don't want to start with some movies in the plist, I would recommend that you just create the file if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: Try this:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `stringByAppendingString:`, you should be using `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`. Otherwise, your path will look like `.../Documentsmovies.plist` (I think).

EDIT: Oh, someone already said in the comments!